# mounting docker cifs volume results in failed to mount local volume: permission denied

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-volume

I want to mount a cifs / smb share for read and write use inside a container. 
I tried everything to mount it directly from the running container, but all methods working around all of dockers security on that matter (--privileged, SYSADMIN, etc.) a) didn't work and b) didn't seem to be a reasonable thing to do.
So, I decided to create a docker volume for the cifs share and mount it on running the container instead.
I create the volume like this:

```
docker volume create \
    --driver local \
    --opt type=cifs \
    --opt o=addr=ip \
    --opt device=//ip/data-root \
    --opt o=username==xxx,password=xxx,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770 \
    --name volz
```

and runninng the container like this `docker run -it --rm --name nuke -v volz:/mnt/z nuke:12.0v2`
results in

> \docker.exe: Error response from daemon: failed to mount local
>   volume: mount  (...) permission denied.

adding `,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp` also didn't help.
Are dockers -v mounts executed as root in the container or with the user the container is started with?

UPDATE:
Mounting the volume to a fresh centos container results in the same error.

Comment: Try to mount the CIFS drive on the host and then use this mount point as a volume in your docker

Comment: I cannot do that as my host is windows, and those cifs volumes dont show under 'shared_drives'. Also workarounds to include them in the menu are not suitable for deploying the containers.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a fix for your issue?

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu